# Facebook question. Post text directly to wall from my website clicking a button

Tags: php, facebook

I have referal system in my website. I want that member of my site could press button and then automatically he would be redirected to facebook with his referal url, text about my website and my youtube video. I searched it in http://developers.facebook.com/plugins , but I couldn't find something like that. Is it even possible to do? Because I think, I have seen it somewhere, so I guess it is. (In twitter I can do it, except the video part)

Thank you very much!

Lol, it is actually like in the SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has a "Share" button which can be customized with JS and  tags.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share

Show the button on the page and add the following tags to your `<header>`:

```
<meta name="medium" content="video" />
<meta name="title" content="MyPageTitle" />
<meta name="og.video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/Ma1_ClRFhwA?fs=1" />
<meta name="og.description" content="MyDescription" />
```